# What is the "object" equivalent in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I would like to create a user defined function that can receive any type. 
My question is what is the type that is equivalent to "object" in language like C#/Java that I need to put on my function.

For example, if I design/call my function like that :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction(@value int)
...
SELECT dbo.MyFunction('a');
```

I will receive the following exception :

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int.
```

Is `varchar(max)` the type I'm looking for? Why?

Comment: no such thing SQL is strongly typed.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: also in this case you could use varchar(1), varchar(max), char(1), char(10) -- but these will not match all types only strings.

Answer (score 2):

[sql_variant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) is the *closest* you'll get, but there are plenty of types (mostly the newer ones) that it won't accept:

> The following table lists the types of values that cannot be stored by using sql_variant:
>
> varchar(max)
>
> varbinary(max)
>
> nvarchar(max)
>
> xml
>
> text
>
> ntext
>
> image
>
> rowversion (timestamp)
>
> sql_variant
>
> geography
>
> hierarchyid
>
> geometry
>
> User-defined types
>
> datetimeoffset

Comment: varbinary should be an only option.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta - but with `varbinary`, you need some out-of-band information to know what the original/intended type is whereas that's embedded in `sql_variant`

Comment: I think the change the OP actually has a problem/requirement where it is correct to use sql_variant at about 5%

Comment: @Hogan - oh, agreed. But it is the closest thing there is to an answer to the question as posed.

Comment: "Change" should be "chance" -- darn you auto-correct!  Oh wait, there is no auto-correct on SO...

Answer (score 0):

If you post a custom object from Javascript, it is serialised as JSON. That's how javascript represents a custom object. Maybe you could do the same.

Comment: This seems like a horrible idea.  SQL Server supports XML natively so that *might* make sense.  But still probably not what the OP actually needs to solve their problem.

Comment: Any kind of loosely typed data type class in SQL is a horrible idea. If it's not strongly typed it's really not suitable for SQL. Usually its a symptom of a lack of data modelling. I'm really just observing how a language that isn't strongly typed handles this with great success.